# How can I find the "same record" in a two tables?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I am trying to do is the following:

[image]

The table on the left is a static table, while the one on the right is where I am  trying to use a formula, I wanna see in which ABCDF the X/Y/Z exist. ie  for example we see above that X exists in A and C.

I think it may need an array way but I couldn't figure out. any tips?

Note: as peter suggested, I can reformat the input table like this:

[image]

Comment: The difficulty is the fact that you use a merged cell for C in the left table. Can you reformat that table so there are no merged cells, i.e. have C in both rows? If you can do that, the formula is very straightforward, if not, it is much trickier.

Comment: ok, what if there's no merged C , but C is repeated instead?

Comment: How can the left table be static? what happens if you have matches on all X, Y and Z for the A row? Is there any reason for which you need to have 2 rows for c instead of having XZ on the same row? That would allow it to not stretch and shrink depending on the matches and it would be easyer to produce with a couple of "if"s. Is there any reason for "E" to be missing? out of curiosity.

Comment: @Wolfaloo in that case it would show on the right table 1 for each of X, Y and Z in row A; by static it means the left table (your left) is manually inputted, it's not generated by some formula.

Comment: OH my bad, i had the relation backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an array formula. You can use the `COUNTIFS` function:
`=COUNTIFS($G$5:$G$10;$J5;$H$5:$H$10;K$4)`
where in my test sheet `G5:G10` is the first column of the left table, `H5:H10` is the second column of the left table, `J5` is the cell with A and `K4` the cell with X in the right table. Please note the mixed `$` signs so you can copy the formula down and right.
Please also note that this will put a 0 if there are no matches, so if you want to leave these cells empty instead, you have to add an additional `IF`.

[image]